# Autoload model and call function inside this model to whole project

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, autoload

I need function (literally i need the `$data`) from this model in whole project. 
when i call in some controller `$data = $this->multi_language_model->multi_lang();` it work fine. But is it possible to call in one place, so I can use in every controller and view.

I autoload the model 
`$autoload['model'] = array('multi_language_model');`

```
class Multi_language_model extends MY_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function multi_lang() {            
        $data['menu_delivery'] = $this->lang->line('menu_delivery');
        $data['menu_quotations'] = $this->lang->line('menu_quotations');
        $data['menu_customer_service'] = $this->lang->line('menu_customer_service');  
    return $data;

   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should create your own library and define it on your project. Here I think there's an idea to start here. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: Please use a helper function so you will get $data from MVC

Comment: When i use helper i get this error.
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object`

Comment: can you show me that code?

Comment: `if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('multi_lang'))
{
    function multi_lang() {
        $data['menu_delivery'] = $this->lang->line('menu_delivery');
        $data['menu_quotations'] = $this->lang->line('menu_quotations');
        $data['menu_customer_service'] = $this->lang->line('menu_customer_service');
}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Put this helper function in your any loaded helper:**

```
function get_multi_lang(){
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $data = array();
    $CI->load->helper('language');
    $CI->lang->load('menu','english');
    $data['menu_delivery'] = $CI->lang->line('menu_delivery');
    $data['menu_quotations'] = $CI->lang->line('menu_quotations');
    $data['menu_customer_service'] = $CI->lang->line('menu_customer_service');  
    return $data;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Yourclassname extends CI_Controller {

    var $menu_delivery = "";
    var $menu_quotations = "";
    var $menu_customer_service = "";

    function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $data = get_multi_lang();
       $this->menu_delivery = $data['menu_delivery'];
       $this->menu_quotations = $data['menu_quotations'];
       $this->menu_customer_service = $data['menu_customer_service'];
    }

    public function index(){
      echo $this->menu_delivery.'<pre>';
      echo $this->menu_quotations.'<pre>';
      echo $this->menu_customer_service.'<pre>';die;
    }
}
```

If you dont want to use helper function then copy helper function lines in controller  __construct() [replace $data to $this->]so direct use global variables do same in model and for view pass this variable via controller

Comment: This give me that $menu_delivery, $menu_quotations, $menu_customer_service are undefined variables

Comment: can you tell me where you write your this line $this->lang->load('filename', 'english');?

Comment: In hooks directory

`class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');

        $site_lang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if ($site_lang) {
            $ci->lang->load('menu',$ci->session->userdata('site_lang'));
        } else {
            $ci->lang->load('menu','english');
        }
    }
}`

Comment: If i call in some controller function is works. But where to call so can I use it $data variables in every controller and view? public function index() { $data = get_multi_lang(); }

Comment: First, Did you try my above-updated code? Is it worked? if yes then accept it,  Second, if you want to call this helper function in every controller's index function then you can use it in the entire controller with controller level global variable which looks like $this->menu_delivery,$this->menu_quotations,$this->menu_customer_service and you have to declare them before the function __construct(){}, According to me you must call this helper function in construct() not in index() function

Comment: But what i need is to call the helper/function in one place. I don't know maybe in MY_Controller, and with extends that controller will be called the helper/function in every controller that extends MY_Controller. Or maybe i need to make $data array global. I don't have any idea how to manage this.

Comment: it means you want to use these three line's data in Model, View, Controller with only one declaration? M I RIGHT?

Comment: It's OK now. I didn't see that you updated your code again. That's what i need. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how codeigniter works but maybe you could do this method static and use it like:

```
class Multi_language_model extends MY_Model
{
    private static $data = [];

    public function get_multi_lang()
    {
        return [
            'menu_delivery' => $this->lang->line('menu_delivery'),
            'menu_quotations' => $this->lang->line('menu_quotations'),
            'menu_customer_service' => $this->lang->line('menu_customer_service'),
        ];
    }

    public static function multi_lang()
    {       
        if (empty(self::$data)) {
            self::$data = (new self)->get_multi_lang();
        }    

        return self::$data;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need it, you can use `$data = Multi_language_model::multi_lang()`;

However, I don't see anything wrong in injecting it from the container, wherever you need it. Doing so would be much easier to build tests.

BTW you don't need to overwrite the class constructor if there are no custom parameters set to the extending class. You can safely remove:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```